# Pullback of $n$-sphere volume form via Gauss map

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, curvature

> Let $M \subset \mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ be a Riemannian hypersurface, and let $N$ be a smooth unit normal vector field along $M$. Denote by $\nu : M \to \mathbb{S}^n$ the Gauss map associated to $N$. Show that $$\nu^*\mathrm{vol}_{\mathbb{S}^n} = (-1)^n K \mathrm{vol}_M, $$ where $K$ is the Gaussian curvature of $M$, $\mathrm{vol}_{\mathbb{S}^n}$ is the standard volume form of $\mathbb{S}^n$, and $\mathrm{vol}_M$ is the volume form of $M$.

I am not particularly sure how to prove this statement. I tried proving this locally, in a coordinate chart, but the computations get messy. More precisely, I am not sure how to relate the volume form on $\mathbb{S}^n$ with the Gaussian curvature of $M$ and its volume form.

Comment: Recall that on one hand the Jacobian of the Gauss map is the second fundamental form, and therefore its determinant is the Gauss curvature. On the other hand, by the change of coordinates formula, the pullback of the volume form on the sphere by the Gauss map is equal to the volume form on $M$ multiplied by the determinant of the Jacobian.

Comment: Where is the $(-1)^n$ coming from?

Comment: Could someone please give a reference for the change of coordinates formula when applied to the pullback of the volume form?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Recall that for an $n$-dimensional real vectorspace $V$ there is the determinant $\det:\mathrm{End}V\to \mathbb R$. On the other hand if $V$ is equipped with an inner product and an orientation one can define $\det_V:V^n\to\mathbb R$ as follows: For $v_1,...,v_n\in V$ choose any positively oriented onb $e_1,...,e_n\in V$ and set $\det_V(v_1,...,v_n)=\det (A)$, where $A$ is the linear map $e_i\mapsto v_i$. In particular ${\det}_{\mathbb R^{n+1}}$ is the volume form on $\mathbb R^{n+1}$.

Now back to the question. Since $\dim M=n$ it suffices to show the equality of $n$-forms at each $p\in M$ applied to a basis. So let $X_1,...,X_n$ be a positively oriented onb of $T_pM$, then

$$\nu^*{\mathrm{vol}_{\mathbb{S}^n}} (X_1,...,X_n)= {\det}_{\mathbb R^{n+1}}(\nu_p,d_p\nu (X_1),...,d_p\nu(X_n))$$

Now we convert this expression into a determinant of a linear map: Since  $\nu_p, X_1,...,X_n$ is a positively oriented onb of $\mathbb R^{n+1}=\langle\nu_p\rangle\oplus T_pM$ we set $A=\mathrm{id}\oplus d_p\nu$. Using $\det (A_2\oplus A_1)=\det A_2\cdot\det A_1$ (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3703848/572257)) the expression above is equal to

$$\det(A)=1\cdot\det(d_p\nu)=(-1)^n\det (d_p-\nu)=(-1)^nK_p\\
=(-1)^nK_p{\mathrm{vol}_M}(X_1,...,X_n)$$

and this is what we wanted to show.

Comment: I don't understand the $-\nu$ that appears here or, for that matter, the factor of $(-1)^n$ in the original statement. It was never specified that $N$ is outward-pointing, but you are assuming that it is, which is fine with me.

Comment: @TedShifrin I don‘t understand what „$N$ is outward-pointing“ should mean here. The convention taken here is, that if a hypersurface comes with a normal field $N$, then the induced orientation is in such way that $(X_1,..,X_n)$ is positively oriented iff $(N,X_1,..,X_n)$ is. For the sphere one takes the outward-pointing normal. $K:=\det(-d\nu)=(-1)^n\det(d\nu)$, which for odd $n$ depends on the choice of $N$. However, given the conventions, the formula above is independent from the choice of $N$.

Comment: OK, fine. I agree. Where is the minus sign coming from? My definition is determinant of the derivative of the Gauss map. Why the negative? Something with the Weingarten map, I suppose, but we need definitions.

Comment: @TedShifrin The definitions i have seen so far are $L:=-d\nu$ for the Weingarten map and $K:=\det L$ (for example in L. Tu‘s and W. Kühnel‘s „Differential Geometry“ books). I don‘t know where this sign convention comes from/what it is good for.